# launching a telegram bot as a windows service

Tags: python, windows, telegram-bot

I want to launch a telegram bot in the form of a Windows service. The bot is hosted on its server with rdp and when the session is disconnected, the bot stops working. I don't want to disable the session timeout, because I wonder if it is possible to run the bot as a service at all.

I ran the command:sc createBot """Service binpath= "C:\Users ****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:\Users ****\Desktop\tg_bot\bot.py " DisplayName= "BotService" start= auto"""
The service was created successfully, I launch it and execute a couple of bot commands, but after a couple of commands, the bot stops working. Are there any other options for implementing this idea, if at all possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.